# Output XML to ASP.NET TextBox with formatting using XmlWriter?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlwriter

I am building an XML string programatically using the XmlWriter ...

```
sb = New StringBuilder()
writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb)

writer.WriteStartDocument()
writer.WriteStartElement("root")

writer.WriteStartElement("element1")
writer.WriteAttributeString("myattribute", "myvalue")
writer.WriteEndElement()

writer.WriteEndElement()
writer.WriteEndDocument()

writer.Flush()

myTextBox.text = "<pre>" & Return sb.ToString() & "</pre>"
```

I want to be able to output the XML to a TextBox control on a ASP.NET webform. When I do output the XML I don't get any line breaks or indentation in the XML. The `XmlWriter` does not seem to have any properties to set formatting. Is there anyway to retain formatting and indentation? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a XmlWriterSettings class instance to specify the use of indentations and line breaks and then pass it into the xmlWriter's Create method.  See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbef2xz3.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. Good example listed there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;


        // Write Xml Declaration with version 1.0 
        writer.WriteStartDocument();


        // Write Xml Document Root Element
        writer.WriteStartElement("Product");


        // Write attribute name and value to current Element 
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ProductID", "01");


        // Write Xml Element with Name and Inner Text
        writer.WriteElementString("ProductName", "P-Name");
        writer.WriteElementString("ProductQuantity","P-Quantity");
        writer.WriteElementString("ProductPrice", "P-Price");

        // Write Product Element closing Tag
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        // Write End of Document 
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        // Flush and Close Writer
        writer.Flush();

        textBox1.Text = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: -1: Don't use `new XmlTextWriter()`. It has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.